# How can I use flexbox to make two items one center one bottom

Tags: css, flexbox

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2n5o.png

I want to achieve a layout like this by flexbox. `body` is flex container and there are only two flex items, one card and one footer. Here is a [simplified codepen link](https://codepen.io/effycoco/pen/GRMEOgZ). How can I make the footer at the bottom of the page while the card position center as it is now.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;  
}

.container {  
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {  
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

if I add `margin-top:auto`, the footer's position will be right, but the container will go to the top.

if I add `gap` to `body`,  the container will not be at the center

Answer (score 2):

Use another element for the green card and make the `.container` fill all the available space using `flex-grow: 1`.

Use `display: flex` and `align-items:center` on the `.container` to center the card vertically.

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  height:100vh;  
}

.container{  
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:green;

}
.footer{  
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background-color:yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

---

The body does not need `justify-content:center;` so you should remove it too.

Another approach if you want that `.container` to have `100%` width.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 100%; /* NEW */
  
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  /* NEW */
}

.card {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto; /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) to center the container, and position to stick the footer.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center; /* center the container */
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  justify-self: center; /* center the footer */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  
  /* push the footer to the bottom */
  position: sticky; 
  top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```